# What are all the different ways that LEGO pieces join together?

Tags: piece-information, building, design

Has anyone made a list of all of the different types of connections between LEGO bricks?

Obviously there's the stud connection - but there's also the ball and socket joint, the more recent click-hinge, the pole-to-minifig-hand connection, and so on.

I suspect there are a quite a few that are specific to a few pieces (eg door hinges or train magnets). What I'm most interested in though are the connections that are part of the overall 'system'.

Comment: It's interesting to note that LEGO is going towards less types of connections; for example, shutters now using a standard clip connection.

Comment: There have been attempts in the LDraw Lego CAD systems to do a parts connection database. I'm yet to hear of them getting to something workable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently in use:

- Stud and "antistud" (diameter 4.6mm)
- Longer studs (Minifig torso)
- Minifig legs
- Minifig neck and head / accessory (eg backpack) - also compatible with studs
- Clip and bar (in a way, similar to stud, but with diameter 3.2mm)
- Wheels (3.2mm axles)
- Flower connector (similar, but even smaller, present in a surprising number of parts, including spider and Technic chain link)
- Technic hole and pin (compatible with studs)
- Technic axle and axle hole
- Turntable
- Click hinges
- Ball joint sockets
- Brick hinges (I'd wager this one is the next one to disappear)
- 9v/RC track connection (discontinued)
- PF electrical plug (discontinued)
- NXT electrical plug (discontinued)
- PU electrical plug
- Train magnets, embedded
- Pneumatic hoses to pneumatic elements and bar elements
- Sliding door in grooves
- Visors on helmets

Decommissioned:

- Flat hinges
- 12v track clip
- 4.5V/12v electrical plugs
- 9V electrical plugs
- Train magnets, free (connects to flowers too...)
- Tube plate hinge (with red tube)
- Wheels (metal pin, as in blue era train wheels)
- Wheels (Plastic pin, as in grey era train wheels)
- ZNAP
- Homemaker arm joints

Comment: When you say brick hinges - I presume you mean these - http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/1133-1.

Comment: There are various window / glass / shutter combinations,  door / frame combinations and wheel / tyre combinations too.

Comment: ...and propellers on shafts, and stickers. Lots and lots of stickers.

Answer (score -2):

Normal, with the studs around the tube
Stud onto tube.
Tile +1 hollow stud to pillar of 1×.
& the edge of a slimbrick between studs. Round 1×1 between studs.
& to pillar (if hole in top).
& some 1× tiles with stud(s) & 5 high have vains, so can take stud midway as well as normal place.

Comment: The terms used here are mostly unclear for me at least, can you explain them? Additionally, due to the ambiguity, it is hard to see whether your points are already included in the wiki answer above.

Comment: Cylinder = tube, between them, into them. Some pieces can fit to pillar of 1× brick. Some such as steep-sloping 1×2 doesn't have pillars, but another way to hold stud.